# Asymptotic rate for the expected value of the square root of sample average

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, asymptotics, limits-and-convergence

I have iid random variables $X_1, \dots, X_n$ with $X_i \geq 0$, $E[X_i]=1$ and $V[X_i] = \sigma^2$.
Let $S_n = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}$.

I'd like to say that $E[\sqrt{S_n}] = 1-O(1/n)$.

My first approach was to write $E[\sqrt{S_n}] = \sqrt{E[S_n] - V[\sqrt{S_n}]} = \sqrt{1-V[\sqrt{S_n}]}$.

I'm then left with showing that $V[\sqrt{S_n}] = O(1/n)$.

I'm unsure how to go about this. First, can I hope to prove such an asymptotic bound in general? If not, are there extra assumptions that can be made on the $X_i$ so that this holds true?

Comment: Taylor expansion of square root at 1 yields $\sqrt{S_n}=1+(S_n-1)/2+O((S_n-1))$.

Comment: Right, this seems to yield something similar to the expression in terms of the variance I have above. Taking expectations on the Taylor expansion, I'd get $E[\sqrt{Sn}] = 1 + E[O(S_n - 1)]$. I'm not sure what to make of that second term.

Comment: The second order term in the Taylor expansion should be $O((S_n - 1)^2)$ of course.

Comment: Yes, I could not correct it. expectation of second order term gives $O(1/n)$.

Comment: How does the asymptotic growth of the second term follow? E.g., why wouldn't this be $O(1/\sqrt{n})$ or $O(1/\log{n})$ or anything else?

Comment: $E((S_n-1)^2)=Var(S_n)=Var(\sum_i X_i)/n^2=n\sigma/n^2=\sigma/n$

Comment: sry $\sigma^2$ of course

Comment: So you're essentially switching the big-O and the expectation, i.e., $E[O((S_n -1)^2)] = O(E[(S_n -1)^2]) = O(1/n)$. Is this always valid, or do we need some extra assumptions for this step?

Comment: You could Taylor expand one order more, i.e. $\sqrt{x}=1+(x-1)/2-(x-1)^2/8+O(((x-1)^3)$. Then it would be left to show that $E[O((S_n-1)^3)]=o(n^{-1})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting $S_n$ for $u$ in the inequalities 
$$\frac{1+u-(u-1)^2}2\le\sqrt u\le\frac{1+u}2$$
for $u\ge0$, taking the expectations, and using that $ES_n=1$ and $E(S_n-1)^2=V(S_n)=\sigma^2/n$, we have 
$$1-\frac{\sigma^2}{2n}\le E\sqrt{S_n}\le1,$$
so that $E\sqrt{S_n}=1-O(1/n)$, as desired.